# Using onclick with switch case procedure and Gradle 8.0, why can I not use the id from the button

Tags: android, audio, switch-statement, constants

I do not use audios in apps often, a few years ago I did and used the following to play audios as required by the user. The R.id.**** is the id of the button.

'''
public void onClick(View v) {

```
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.zeroen:
            this.mySounds.play(this.pthisispauljonesen, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1, 0, 1.0f);
            break;
        case R.id.zerocn:
            this.mySounds.play(this.pthisispauljonescn, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1, 0, 1.0f);
            break;
        case R.id.oneen:
            this.mySounds.play(this.pthisismrsmithen, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1, 0, 1.0f);
            break;

        case R.id.onecn:
            this.mySounds.play(this.pthisismrsmithcn, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1, 0, 1.0f);
            break;
      }
}
```

'''

I am now being told I can not use this method because I am use Gradle 8.0.
See picture for exact message, what do I have to do to solve this?

[image: Error Message]